# displaying xml child elements in PHP

Tags: php, xml, nodes, children

Not a total n00b but never really dabbled with XML

I have an XML feed which when queried returns this response

```
<ContentAPI xmlns="http://www.geneity.co.uk/genbet/ContentAPI" status="OK" timezone="UTC" msg_stamp="NDczMTUwNjIyOjEwMDM6ZW4=" version="1.0" request="get_events_for_type">
<Sport sport_code="FOOT" name="Football" disporder="-1000">
<SBClass sb_class_id="12430" disporder="-999" name="United Kingdom">
<SBType sb_type_id="19157" name="Eng - Premier League" disporder="-1001">
<Ev inplay_allowed="Y" status="A" name="West Ham United v Liverpool" start_time="2016-01-02T12:45:00" virtual="N" ev_timezone="Europe/London" inplay_now="N" mkt_count="128" ev_id="3341306" disporder="-9999">
<EvDetail br_match_id="7464844"/>
<Teams>
<Team team_id="239" team_order="0" name="West Ham United" short_name="West Ham United"/>
<Team team_id="2577" team_order="1" name="Liverpool" short_name="Liverpool"/>
</Teams>
</Ev>
<Ev inplay_allowed="Y" status="A" name="Leicester City v Bournemouth" start_time="2016-01-02T15:00:00" virtual="N" ev_timezone="Europe/London" inplay_now="N" mkt_count="128" ev_id="3330641" disporder="-9999">
<EvDetail br_match_id="7464832"/>
<Teams>
<Team team_id="708" team_order="0" name="Leicester City" short_name="Leicester City"/>
<Team team_id="101178" team_order="1" name="Bournemouth" short_name="Bournemouth"/>
</Teams>
</Ev>
<Ev inplay_allowed="Y" status="A" name="Arsenal v Newcastle" start_time="2016-01-02T15:00:00" virtual="N" ev_timezone="Europe/London" inplay_now="N" mkt_count="127" ev_id="3341307" disporder="-9999">
<EvDetail br_match_id="7464826"/>
<Teams>
<Team team_id="96" team_order="0" name="Arsenal" short_name="Arsenal"/>
<Team team_id="1347" team_order="1" name="Newcastle" short_name="Newcastle"/>
</Teams>
</Ev>
<Ev inplay_allowed="Y" status="A" name="Manchester United v Swansea" start_time="2016-01-02T15:00:00" virtual="N" ev_timezone="Europe/London" inplay_now="N" mkt_count="127" ev_id="3341308" disporder="-9999">
<EvDetail br_match_id="7464834"/>
<Teams>
<Team team_id="2494" team_order="0" name="Manchester United" short_name="Manchester United"/>
<Team team_id="1351" team_order="1" name="Swansea" short_name="Swansea"/>
</Teams>
</Ev>
</SBType>
</SBClass>
</Sport>
</ContentAPI>
```

Im using the code

```
$xmlData = 'http://feeds-sports.winner.com/odds_feed?key=get_events_for_type&lang=en&&sb_type_id=19157';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlData);

print $xml->Sport->attributes()->{'name'} .' - ';
print $xml->Sport->SBClass->attributes()->{'name'} .' <br /><br />';
print $xml->Sport->SBClass->SBType->attributes()->{'name'} .' <br />';
//print $xml->Sport->SBClass->SBType->Ev->attributes()->{'name'} .' <br />';

foreach ($xml->Sport->SBClass->SBType->Ev->Teams->Team as $team){
print $xml->Sport->SBClass->SBType->Ev->attributes()->{'name'} .' <br />';

//print $team->attributes()->{'short_name'} . ' vs ' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Its not printing new records each time just the same one

Any help would be hugely appreciated. I'm just pulling my hair out at the minute because I know its something easy

Comment: You can for example use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: I've tried SimpleXML but stil cant figure it out

I tried with the usual <note> example XML files
but I cant get these to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your `xml` sample and adding a closing `Ev` tag

```
<ContentAPI xmlns="http://www.geneity.co.uk/genbet/ContentAPI" status="OK" timezone="UTC" msg_stamp="MDoxOmVu" version="1.0" request="get_events_for_type">
<Sport sport_code="FOOT" name="Football">
<SBClass sb_class_id="12430" name="United Kingdom">
<SBType sb_type_id="19157" name="Barclays Premier League">
<Ev inplay_allowed="Y" status="A" name="Aston Villa v Norwich City" start_time="2012-10-27T11:45:00" ev_timezone="Europe/London" inplay_now="N" mkt_count="102" ev_id="26301">
<Teams>
<Team team_id="1323" team_order="0" name="Aston Villa" short_name="Aston Villa"/>
<Team team_id="136" team_order="1" name="Norwich City" short_name="Norwich City"/>
</Teams>
</Ev>
</SBType>
</SBClass>
</Sport>
</ContentAPI>
```

You can access each `xml` node as follows

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');

print $xml->Sport->attributes()->{'name'} . PHP_EOL;
print $xml->Sport->SBClass->attributes()->{'name'} . PHP_EOL;
print $xml->Sport->SBClass->SBType->attributes()->{'name'} . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($xml->Sport->SBClass->SBType->Ev->Teams->Team as $team){

    print $team->attributes()->{'short_name'} . PHP_EOL;

}
```

Which will output

```
Football
United Kingdom
Barclays Premier League
Aston Villa
Norwich City
```